# Bootstrap Editable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code for bootstrap editable. I can't able to get the span id value. Please help me to fix this.

```
<span class="xedit" id="firstname"><?= $pfname ?></span>                                                               
<span class="xedit" id="lastname"><?= $plname ?></span>

<script>
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $('.xedit').editable();
    $(document).on('click', '.editable-submit', function () {
        var columnvalue = $('.input-sm').val();
        alert($(this).parents('span:first').attr('id'));
        alert(columnvalue);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.editable-submit', function () {
      alert($('#firstname').val());
    });
```

I think this should do